# 2D xy slice from a 3d array

Tags: matlab

i have a grid of 512*1024*488, (x,y,z) i have the following script to read the data and then plot a contour of the 2d slice

```
    %function [rtime,itime,dt,nx,ny,nz,deltax,deltay,rlenz,u,v,w] = Read_vel3d(name)
% _________________________________________________________________________
% name;
fid    = fopen('vel.451000', 'rb');
% fid;
rtime  = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
itime  = fread(fid, 1,          'int32');
dt     = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
nx0    = fread(fid, 1,          'int32');
ny0    = fread(fid, 1,          'int32');
nz     = fread(fid, 1,          'int32');
deltax = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
deltay = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
rlenz  = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
utoto  = fread(fid, nx0*ny0*nz, 'float64');
vtoto  = fread(fid, nx0*ny0*nz, 'float64');
wtoto  = fread(fid, nx0*ny0*nz, 'float64');
fclose(fid);

u = reshape(utoto,[nx0,ny0,nz]);
v = reshape(vtoto,[nx0,ny0,nz]);
w = reshape(wtoto,[nx0,ny0,nz]);

nx = nx0-1;
ny = ny0-1;

display('Contour Plot');

A = squeeze(u(138,:,:));
figure
figure('visible','on')
contourf(A);
colormap jet;
hold on
colorbar;
```

i understand the when i do:

```
A = squeeze(u(:,:,138));
```

it creates a single dimension in the z and then plots the array 1024*512, so 1024 on the x and then 512 in the y, this is correct however when i do:

```
A = squeeze(u(138,:,:));
```

it again creates a single dimension in the x and then plots the array 488*1024, so 488 in the x and then 1024 in the y, this is where the problem is. in this slice the x should be 1024 and the y should be 488, but i am unsure of how to do this.

Comment: Yes, this is what it's supposed to do. If you want the dimensions swapped you can just transpose the result of `squeeze`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes thats what i want, but how do i do the transpose of it, this is what was confusing me bit

Comment: Like that? [`.'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)

Comment: i know to do a transpose of a matrix you would do for example u', but i want to know how do i do it for the result of the squeeze, so that i can plot the contour 2d slice. what will the squeeze line of the code be followed by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to get a 2D slice from high dimension data is to use *squeeze* as you do, and when needed (depending on your preference of orientation) to transpose the slice as one of the comments suggested. However I would recommend to use *permute*. The advantage of *permute* is that, in the rare case that a dimension of a slice is singular, you still get correct orientation, while *squeeze* will squeeze the singular dimension out.

Either way, you will need to do it differently when you extract from different dimension:

```
if isDim1 % extract slice from 1st dim
    A = permute(u(138, :, :), [2 3 1]); % could be [3 2 1]
elseif isDim2 % extract slice from 2nd dim
    A = permute(u(:, 138, :), [3 1 2]); % could be [1 3 2]
else % 3rd dim
    A = u(:, :, 138); % could be A = permute(u(:, :, 138), [2 1 3]);
end
```